# PHP Unique pageviews counter not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, web-analytics, pageviews

The following script updates the pageviews if its from a unique visitor. The page retrieves blog posts from databases and prints on the screen. When a  blog post is visited first time the script should update its pageview field by 1. But the script is updating the pageview on every page refresh rather than recording only unique views.

```
if($_SESSION[$isPostID] != $isPostID)
{
   try
   {
        $updatePageViews = $db2->prepare("UPDATE articles SET pageviews = pageviews+1 WHERE id = :id");
        $updatePageViews->execute(array(':id' => $isPostID));
        if($updatePageViews->rowCount() != 1)
        {
            @createLog("Unable to update pageviews.","Unable to update pageviews!!! Title = [".$istitle."].");
        }
        else{ $_SESSION[$isPostID] = $isPostID;}
   }
   catch(PDOException $updatePageViewsERR)
   {
        $subject = "Pageviews Updation--Update data into database. [PAGE= ".$istitle."]. Error Code: #15";
        $text = $updatePageViewsERR->getMessage();
        @createLog($subject,$text);
   }
}
```

$isPostID is the unique ID assigned to every blog post in the database table.
Note: Session is already started in the script.

Comment: First of all, are you sure the sessions mechanism work? Is session_start() in place / automated ? Have you tried printing the `$_SESSION` out and see what's in it?

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in the first line.

First: you have no closing parenthesis in the condition. I guess it's just a typo, otherwise it would throw you fatal errors.

Second: you are comparing `$isPostID` to `$isPostId` which are two different variables. This may be exactly why it doesn't work.

See if it solves the problem

Comment: While comparing those two variables, they are same. I had edited the source code. but they are still not working as they are expected to.